# Template Error: Every default member must be a string Coludformation yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to build my cloudformation script using yml and i think it came out good. But, when i try to create a new stack using this file, it gives **Template Error: Every default member must be a string.**
I searched for this error and  tried multiple things but no luck. Could you please provide your inputs if i am missing anything in the syntax. Below is the what i added in the yml file.

Basically, i have a 2 parameters AccountAccessKey and AccountName which have one value for non-prod and other for prod and i am trying to get that values dynamically by defining a map and usingthem in the parameters section. After, i am calling them using $AccountAccessKey and $AccountName in the 3rd section.

Any inputs would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
  AccountAccessKey:
    Description: AccountAccessKey
    Type: String
    Default: !FindInMap [ AccountAccessKeyMap, !Ref "AWS::Region", !Ref Environment ]

  AccountName:
    Description: AccountName
    Type: String
    Default: !FindInMap [ AccountNameMap, !Ref "AWS::Region", !Ref Environment ]
 
  AccountAccessKeyMap:
    us-east-1:
      dev: asdfsfsfasd4
      qa:  asdfsfsfasd4
      prod: 88yuuiuyiui
    us-west-2:
      dev: asdfsfsfasd4
      qa:  asdfsfsfasd4
      prod: 88yuuiuyiui

  AccountNameMap:
    us-east-1:
      dev: nonprod
      qa:  nonprod
      prod: prod1
    us-west-2:
      dev: nonprod
      qa:  nonprod
      prod: prod1
      
      
  "/usr/dev/agent/conf/info.xml":
               content:
                  Fn::Sub:
                     - |
                        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                        <controller-info>
                        <account-access-key>${AccountAccessKey}</account-access-key>
                        <account-name>${AccountName}</account-name>                                            
                        </controller-info>
                     - {Server: !FindInMap [ ServerMap, !Ref "AWS::Region", !Ref Environment ]}
```

Comment: We can't use intrinsic functions in parameter section of template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't use [intrinsic functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html) in parameters. In this case, we can slighly refactor mappings and remove parameters completely, since we are using the value from mappings anyhow.

`!FindInMap [AccountNameMap, !Ref AWS::Region, !Ref Environment]` for other attributes also inside the template itself.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: "Test"
Parameters:
  Environment:
    Type: String
    Default: dev

Mappings:
  AccountAccessKeyMap:
    us-east-1:
      dev: mydeveastkey
      qa: myqaeastkey
      prod: myprodeastkey
    us-west-2:
      dev: mydevwestkey
      qa: myqawestkey
      prod: myprodwestkey
  AccountNameMap:
    us-east-1:
      dev: mydeveastname
      qa: myqaeastname
      prod: myprodeastnaem
    us-west-2:
      dev: mydevwestname
      qa: myqawestname
      prod: myprodwestname
Resources:
  SmsLambdaParameter:
    Type: "AWS::SSM::Parameter"
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub
        - "/${EnvFullUpper}/Lambda-Param/Test"
        - { EnvFullUpper: !Ref Environment }
      Type: "String"
      Value: !Sub
        - '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
          <controller-info>
          <account-access-key>${AccountAccessKey}</account-access-key>
          <account-name>${AccountName}</account-name>
          </controller-info>
          '
        - {
            AccountAccessKey:
              !FindInMap [
                AccountAccessKeyMap,
                !Ref AWS::Region,
                !Ref Environment,
              ],
            AccountName:
              !FindInMap [AccountNameMap, !Ref AWS::Region, !Ref Environment],
          }
```